# Site oneboxes are often white, invisible

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, chat, onebox

Oneboxing of site links is often not visible, especially on beta sites:

> [image]

Many sites, like Ask Ubuntu and Sharepoint also have predominantly white logos in oneboxes.

These images should have a background colour, so that they are visible.

1. chat.stackoverflow.com has a slightly off-white background, so the white content is still slightly visible. chat.stackexchange has a pure-white background, white content is *gone*.
2. the one-box for `http://stackexchange.com` is pure white, and looks like:

   > [image: white background]

   at least on chat.stackoverflow the white is visible:

   > [image: Chat.stackoverflow]

Comment: I agree they are very hard to see because of this.

Comment: @Benny can't you bring this up directly to the staff in the TL chat room? Bug reports here fall below the radar many times.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good suggestion. I'll try to announce them in a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: Well, one possible solution is giving background color to the parent div when oneboxing site logo, e.g. with blue background the result is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2DXYt.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard But then what about blue logos? :-P The best solution, as far as I can tell, is to use a colour from the [api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true), or just use the `icon_url` and text name instead.

Comment: Good point @fredley, was just looking for a quick and not-so-elegant fix that might be implemented faster.

Comment: Click [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3875645#3875645) link to see the UX logo clearly

Comment: related: [Speaking of User Experience](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/1714/33494) on UX meta

Comment: Given the relatively minor impact that this has we won't be handling this.